# System-verilog generate module instances and pass input/process output data

Tags: system-verilog

I wrote a module in System Verilog, I need 32 modules, so I am using generate statement for instantiation.

The problem is that in every rising edge of clock I need to instantiate new values to the modules and then need to choose one of them (in the same `posedge clock`, depending on the outputs of the modules, in my case the min between all the module output).

How can I do that?

This is my current version of the code:

```
    genvar j; 
    generate 
        for (int j=0; j<32; j++)
         begin: module_instant_loop
            always @(posedge Clock)
               begin
                  MyUnit unit[j] (.A(TEST1[j],.B(TEST2[j]),.OUT(MYOUT[j]);
               end              
            end
         end
    endgenerate
```

And this is the code that I want to add:

```
for (int i=0; i<32; i++)
    begin
        if (MYOUT[i] < MINIMUM) MINIMUM=MYOUT[i];
        if (MYOUT[i] > MAXIMUM) MAXIMUM=MYOUT[i];
    end
```

How can I add the loop to my code?

Comment: You shouldn't have the ```int``` in the for loop inside the generate statement - j is already declared as a genvar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot instantiate a module instance inside an always block. You choices are to move the synchronous logic inside `MyUnit` or flop the output `MyUnit` at the same level.

Typically, you want to flop your final outputs. You may put some combinational logic after the flop, but be aware this can can make flop-to-flop timing across different modules harder to calculate.

So assuming `MINIMUM` and `MAXIMUM` are the values you want flopped, I would recommend the following logic:

```
always_comb begin
  // Set defaults
  next_MINIMUM = '1; // fill with all 1s
  next_MAXIMUM = '0; // fill with all 0s

  // Alternative default with the previous MIN/MAX values
  //next_MINIMUM = MINIMUM;
  //next_MAXIMUM = MAXIMUM;

  // Update MIN/MAX based on MYOUT
  foreach(MYOUT[idx]) begin // IEEE Std 1800-2012 12.7.3 The foreach-loop
    if (MYOUT[idx] < next_MINIMUM) next_MINIMUM=MYOUT[idx];
    if (MYOUT[idx] > next_MAXIMUM) next_MAXIMUM=MYOUT[idx];
  end
end

always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
  MINIMUM <= next_MINIMUM;
  MAXIMUM <= next_MAXIMUM;
end
```

It is a best practice to always assign a flop with non-blocking. Blocking assignments are needed to properly calculate the next value. Therefore, the intermediate signals `next_*`. When using SystemVerilog, it is recommend to use `always_comb` and `always_ff` instead of `always` (See [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 9.2.2.2.2 *always_comb compared to always @**).